# I keep getting the "TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable", can someone help me?

Tags: python, pygame

Im having troubles on how to fix the "TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable" issue, the line with issue is 78 under the enemy function

```
SCREEN.blit(enemy_pic[i], (x, y))
```

And if anyone has some extra time, does anyone have any ideas on how to make each individual enemy have the ability to shoot a bullet towards the player and make each of the enemies collidable?

```
import pygame, sys, random, time
from button import Button

pygame.init()

#Mechanic variables
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
SCREEN_width = 1280
SCREEN_height = 720
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_width, SCREEN_height))
FPS = 500
i = 0

#Coordinats
player_x = 500
player_y = 500

enemy_x = 0
enemy_y = 0

#Change in coordinats
player_x_change = 0
player_y_change = 0

enemy_x_change = 0
enemy_y_change = 0

#Pictures
BG_placeholder = pygame.image.load("assets/PlaceholderBG.png")
BGmenu = pygame.image.load("assets/Background.png")
player_pic = pygame.image.load("assets/Tunak_tunka_tun_player_standing_still.png")
enemy_pic = pygame.image.load("assets/PlaceholderBG.png")
levelMap = pygame.image.load("assets/Level.png")


#Transforming or scaling the pictures/images
BG_placeholder = pygame.transform.scale(BG_placeholder, (50, 50))
BGmenu = pygame.transform.scale(BGmenu, (SCREEN_width, SCREEN_height))
player_pic = pygame.transform.scale(player_pic, (50, 50))
enemy_pic = pygame.transform.scale(enemy_pic, (50, 50))
levelMap = pygame.transform.scale(levelMap, (SCREEN_width, SCREEN_height))

#Icon & Caption
icon = pygame.display.set_icon(BG_placeholder)
pygame.display.set_caption("Den Indiske Joede Kirke")

#Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

#enemy
enemyImg = []
enemy_x = []
enemy_y = []
num_of_enemies = 6
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
      enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load("assets/PlaceholderBG.png"))
      enemy_x.append(random.randint(0, SCREEN_width))
      enemy_y.append(random.randint(0, SCREEN_height))
      enemyImg[i] = pygame.transform.scale(enemyImg[i], (50, 50))

#Functions
def player(x, y):
    SCREEN.blit(player_pic, (x, y))

def get_font(size):
    return pygame.font.Font("assets/font.ttf", size)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def enemy(x, y, i):
    SCREEN.blit(enemy_pic[i], (x, y))

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((SCREEN_width/2), (SCREEN_height/2))
    SCREEN.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def game_menu():
        while True:
            SCREEN.blit(BGmenu, (0, 0))

            MENU_MOUSE_POS = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            MENU_TEXT = get_font(90).render("Menu", True, "#47df0a")
            MENU_RECT = MENU_TEXT.get_rect(center=(640, 100))

            PLAY_BUTTON = Button(image=pygame.image.load("assets/Play Rect.png"), pos=(640, 300),
                                 text_input="PLAY", font=get_font(75), base_color="#9ce597", hovering_color="White")
            QUIT_BUTTON = Button(image=pygame.image.load("assets/Quit Rect.png"), pos=(640, 500),
                                 text_input="QUIT", font=get_font(75), base_color="#9ce597", hovering_color="White")

            SCREEN.blit(MENU_TEXT, MENU_RECT)

            for button in [PLAY_BUTTON, QUIT_BUTTON]:
                button.changeColor(MENU_MOUSE_POS)
                button.update(SCREEN)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if PLAY_BUTTON.checkForInput(MENU_MOUSE_POS):
                        game_loop()
                    if QUIT_BUTTON.checkForInput(MENU_MOUSE_POS):
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

            pygame.display.update()

def game_loop():
    global player_x, player_y, enemy_x, enemy_y, player_x_change, player_y_change, enemy_x_change, enemy_y_change
    game = True
    while game:
        SCREEN.fill(white)
        SCREEN.blit(levelMap, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player_x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player_y_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player_y_change = 5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_x_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player_y_change = 0
        player_x += player_x_change
        player_y += player_y_change

        if player_x <= 0:
            player_x = 0
        elif player_x >= 1230:
            player_x = 1230
        if player_y <= 0:
            player_y = 0
        elif player_y >= 670:
            player_y = 670

        player(player_x, player_y)
        for i in range(num_of_enemies):
            enemy(enemy_x[i], enemy_y[i], i)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)

game_menu()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the `Surface` class doesn't declare `__getitem__()` method and can't be called with the indexing syntax like `enemy_pic[1]`.

So probably you should pass just an instance of `Surface` to [`SCREEN.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) like `SCREEN.blit(enemy_pic, (x, y))` to put one surface on another.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to just draw the same surface eg. *enemy_pic* at the position of your enemies. That way you just store position of different enemies.

```py
enemies = []

for i in range(10):
    enemies.append([random.randint(0, SCREEN_width), random.randint(0, SCREEN_height)])

# then at your game loop

for enemy_pos in enemies:
    SCREEN.blit(enemy_pic, enemy_pos)
```

Collisions are harder and more complicated to implement. Hopefully there is a library for collisions called [pymunk](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/index.html) which is fairly straight-forward to use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `enemy_pic` is a pygame surface, initialised by:

```
enemy_pic = pygame.image.load("assets/PlaceholderBG.png")
```

It's then resized, but still a surface. Your code then expects it to be a sequence of images.

You create a list of images, `enemyImg` which is what you want to be referring to instead of `enemy_pic`.

So you could change `enemy()`:

```
def enemy(x, y, i):
    SCREEN.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))
```

But looking at how you call `enemy()`:

```
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemy(enemy_x[i], enemy_y[i], i)
```

It might be easier to change `enemy()` to:

```
def enemy(i):
    SCREEN.blit(enemyImg[i], (enemy_x[i], enemy_y[i]))
```

Longer term it will become increasingly difficult to work with this code, so I'd recommend learning about and implementing [sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).